# AWS Glue error converting data frame to dynamic frame

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

Here's my code where I am trying to create a new data frame out of the result set of my left join on other 2 data frames and then trying to convert it to a dynamic frame.

```
dfs = sqlContext.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).options(**sfOptions).option("query", "SELECT hashkey as hash From randomtable").load()

#Source
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "test", table_name = "randomtable", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

#add hash value
df = datasource0.toDF()
df.cache()
df = df.withColumn("hashkey", sha2(concat_ws("||", *df.columns), 256))

#drop dupes
df1 = df.dropDuplicates(subset=['hashkey'])

#read incremental data
inc = df1.join(dfs, df1["hashkey"] == dfs["hash"], how='left').filter(col('hash').isNull())

#convert it back to glue context
datasource1 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(inc, glueContext, "datasource1")
```

Here is the error I get when trying to convert a data frame to a dynamic frame.

> datasource1 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(inc, glueContext, "datasource1")
>   File
>   "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1560272525947_0002/container_1560272525947_0002_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/dynamicframe.py",
>
> line 150, in fromDF
>       File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1560272525947_0002/container_1560272525947_0002_01_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1133, in **call**
>       File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1560272525947_0002/container_1560272525947_0002_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
>   line 63, in deco
>       File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1560272525947_0002/container_1560272525947_0002_01_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
>   line 319, in get_return_value
>       py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame.apply.
>       : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeReference.(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType;ZLorg/apache/spark/sql/types/Metadata;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/ExprId;Lscala/collection/Seq;)V
>       at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.pushdowns.querygeneration.QueryHelper$$anonfun$8.apply(QueryHelper.scala:66)
>       at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.pushdowns.querygeneration.QueryHelper$$anonfun$8.apply(QueryHelper.scala:65)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
>       at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.pushdowns.querygeneration.QueryHelper.(QueryHelper.scala:64)
>       at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.pushdowns.querygeneration.SourceQuery.(SnowflakeQuery.scala:100)
>       at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.pushdowns.querygeneration.QueryBuilder.net$snowflake$spark$snowflake$pushdowns$querygeneration$QueryBuilder$$generateQueries(QueryBuilder.scala:98)
>       at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.pushdowns.querygeneration.QueryBuilder.liftedTree1$1(QueryBuilder.scala:63)
>       at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.pushdowns.querygeneration.QueryBuilder.treeRoot$lzycompute(QueryBuilder.scala:61)
>       at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.pushdowns.querygeneration.QueryBuilder.treeRoot(QueryBuilder.scala:60)
>       at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.pushdowns.querygeneration.QueryBuilder.tryBuild$lzycompute(QueryBuilder.scala:34)
>       at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.pushdowns.querygeneration.QueryBuilder.tryBuild(QueryBuilder.scala:33)
>       at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.pushdowns.querygeneration.QueryBuilder$.getRDDFromPlan(QueryBuilder.scala:179)
>       at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.pushdowns.SnowflakeStrategy.buildQueryRDD(SnowflakeStrategy.scala:42)
>       at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.pushdowns.SnowflakeStrategy.apply(SnowflakeStrategy.scala:24)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:62)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:62)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:92)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:77)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:66)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:92)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:77)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:66)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:92)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:77)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: any specific reason why you want to convert it back to Dynamic Frame?

Comment: @HarshBafna wouldn't it need to be converted back to DynamicFrame to complete the Glue crawl successfully?

Comment: @roy : its not mandatory to convert back to DynamicFrame. Generally, you would like to write the dataframe back to disk which can be done directly i.e. without converting back to DynamicFrame

Comment: @roy I am trying to output this data to redshift which needs me to convert my DF to dynamic frame.

Comment: have you see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60251975/create-dynamic-frame-from-options-from-rds-mysql-providing-a-custom-query-wi I think is relevant