# Create dynamic frame from options (from rds - mysql) providing a custom query with where clause

Tags: mysql, dataframe, where-clause, aws-glue, amazon-aurora

I want to create a DynamicFrame in my Glue job from an Aurora-rds mysql table. Can I create DynamicFrame from my rds table using a custom query - having a where clause?
I dont want to read the entire table every time in my DynamicFrame and then filter later. 
Looked at this website but didnt find any option here or elsewhere, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html

**Construct JDBC connection options**

> connection_mysql5_options = {
>       "url": "jdbc:mysql://:3306/db",
>       "dbtable": "test",
>       "user": "admin",
>       "password": "pwd"}

**Read DynamicFrame from MySQL 5**

> df_mysql5 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type="mysql",
>                    connection_options=connection_mysql5_options)

Is there any way to give a where clause and say select only top 100 rows from test table, say it has a column named "id" and I want to fetch using this query:

> select * from test where id<100;

Appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: I found this today, and probably is what you are looking for too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388993/aws-glue-predicate-push-down-condition-has-no-effect

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, I would have made a comment but I do not have sufficient reputation. I was able to make the solution that Guillermo AMS provided work within AWS Glue, but it did require two changes:

- The "jdbc" format was unrecognized (the provided error was: "py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o79.load.
  : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: jbdc. Please find packages at [http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html"](http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html%22)) -- I had to use the full name: "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider"
- The query option was not working for me (the provided error was: "py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o72.load.
  : java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character"), but fortunately, the "dbtable" option supports passing in either a table or a subquery -- that is using parentheses around a query.

In my solution below I have also added a bit of context around the needed objects and imports.
My solution ended up looking like:

```
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

glue_context = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

tmp_data_frame = glue_context.spark_session.read\
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider")\
  .option("url", jdbc_url)\
  .option("user", username)\
  .option("password", password)\
  .option("dbtable", "(select * from test where id<100)")\
  .load()
```

Comment: I tried this, I am getting communications link failure.

Answer (score 0):

The way I was able to provide a custom query was by creating a Spark DataFrame and specifying it with options:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#manually-specifying-options

Then transform that DataFrame into a DynamicFrame using said class:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html

```
tmp_data_frame = spark.read.format("jbdc")
.option("url", jdbc_url)
.option("user", username)
.option("password", password)
.option("query", "select * from test where id<100")
.load()

dynamic_frame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(tmp_data_frame, glueContext)
```