# JDBC driver for SQL Server (java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

Before pushing my python code to glue job I'm trying to test it locally but encountered following issue:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o35.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$driverClass$2(JDBCOptions.scala:108)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:354)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:326)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:308)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:308)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:226)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My code is following:
I tried using `config` parameter but also didn't work. The jar file for jdbc driver is located in same location as python script.

`.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "C:/python_code/mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre15.jar") \`

Script triggerd with: `C:\pyth_code>spark-submit code.py`

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()


jdbc_df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://mssql-server.xxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:xxxx") \
    .option("query", "SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE FROM db_name.information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'RDM'") \
    .option("user", user) \
    .option("password", pass) \
    .load()

jdbc_df.show()
```

Env variables:

[image]

MS' jdbc driver location:

[image]

UPDATE - using gluecontext fixed driver issue but gave new one:

```
glue_context = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
jdbc_df_t = glue_context.spark_session.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://mssql-rds-development.xxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:xxxx") \
    .option("query", "SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE FROM information_schema.columns") \
    .option("user", user) \
    .option("password", pass) \
    .load()
```

Error after using gluecontext:

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\awsglue\context.py", line 45, in __init__
    self._glue_scala_context = self._get_glue_scala_context(**options)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\awsglue\context.py", line 66, in _get_glue_scala_context
    return self._jvm.GlueContext(self._jsc.sc())
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't expect you will need to use a custom JDBC driver, try the below without it (as in my recent answer here:
[Create dynamic frame from options (from rds - mysql) providing a custom query with where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60251975/create-dynamic-frame-from-options-from-rds-mysql-providing-a-custom-query-wi/67406855#67406855))

This block should do the trick:

```
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

glue_context = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

jdbc_df = glue_context.spark_session.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://mssql-server.xxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:xxxx") \
    .option("dbtable", "(SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE FROM db_name.information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'RDM')") \
    .option("user", user) \
    .option("password", pass) \
    .load()
```

Comment: Getting closer but got error: `  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\awsglue\context.py", line 45, in __init__
    self._glue_scala_context = self._get_glue_scala_context(**options)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\awsglue\context.py", line 66, in _get_glue_scala_context
    return self._jvm.GlueContext(self._jsc.sc())
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable`

Comment: Sorry upon a re-read of your question it appears you are using pyspark directly in windows, I missed that. I suggest that you try uploading the code to AWS and see what happens. Running windows code to talk to RDS brings a host of networking challenges that you would need to address (but that isn't the error you are seeing of course). Note that in the configuration of your glue job you shouldn't need to specify any sort of jdbc driver.

Comment: yes, after loading to AWS both versions (spark/glue context) work with no issues. I wanted to avoid constant uploading and running in order to run the script locally. What do you mean by not specifying jdbc driver?

Comment: I am not sure that the java libraries Spark is using locally will have the injections in place that are used when Spark is hosted by AWS Glue, so I am uncertain what your are trying will work locally; you have gone beyond my expertise :). If you do want to work locally you may want to use local files / data loaded into a data frame or dynamic frame (say via a unit test pattern) instead of connecting to RDS as a test bed, that is what I do. How to locally unit test a glue job may be best suited as a separate question.

Comment: I did new findings. Now it seems python module is causing issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67528218/py4jerror-while-running-gluecontext-script

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was able to test my code locally with JDBC as below. Runtime property "spark.jars" need to be set to include the driver jar. For more details please check this link https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

```
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("SA_Intro") \
        .master("local[2]") \
        .config("spark.jars", "/path-to-jar/mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar") \
        .getOrCreate()

    df = spark.read.jdbc("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=user&password=password",
                     table="table_name",
                     properties={"driver": 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'})
```

Similarly it can be done as below:

```
    df = spark.read \
        .format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test") \
        .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") \
        .option("dbtable", "table_name") \
        .option("user", "user") \
        .option("password", "password") \
        .load()
```